# Dialogo JSF se cierra automaticamente

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo este commandButtom

```java
<h:commandButton value="Nuevo Producto" onclick="PF('prod').show()" />
```

Este abre el dialogo a continuacion mostrado

```java
<p:dialog widgetVar="prod" modal="true" resizable="false" header="Producto">
            <h:form id="dataNew">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nombre del producto" for="txtNombre"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText id="txtNombre" value="#{managedProducto.producto.nombreProducto}"></h:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Descripcion del producto"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{managedProducto.producto.descripcionProducto}"></h:inputTextarea>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Marca del producto"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText value="#{managedProducto.producto.marcaProducto}"></h:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Modelo del producto"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText value="#{managedProducto.producto.modeloProducto}"></h:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Existencias del producto"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText value="#{managedProducto.producto.existencias}"></h:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Precio unitario del producto"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText value="#{managedProducto.producto.precioUnitario}"></h:inputText>
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{managedProducto.producto.codigoProveedor}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="--- SELECCIONAR ---"></f:selectItem>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{managedProveedor.listaProveedor}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.nombreProveedor}"
                                           itemValue="#{p.idProveedor}"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:commandButton  actionListener="#{managedProducto.insertarProducto()}" 
                                      rendered="#{managedProducto.producto.idProducto == 0}" 
                                      onclick="PF('prod').hide()" value="Guardar"/>
                    <h:commandButton  actionListener="#{managedProducto.modificarProducto()}" 
                                      rendered="#{managedProducto.producto.idProducto != 0}" 
                                      onclick="PF('prod').hide()" value="Modificar"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Y de momento no hay problema, pero el dialogo abre unicamente fracciones de segundo es decir, se cierra el solo, al principio pense que era mi navegador puesto que tiene algunas restricciones en cuanto a dialogos emergentes y use otro navegador pero el problema persiste, alguien de casualidad sabe que podria ocasionar el problema

Comment: prueba cambiar los h:commandButton a p:commandButton